# IE8 ignoring white space in gwt TextArea

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, textarea, uibinder

I am developing a GWT project zfapp.

I have an UIBinder notch.ui.xml. I have a problem in the gwt TextArea in this UIBinder. When displaying text, IE8 and above are ignoring white space!

It's working fine with IE7, Fire Fox , Chrome, etc...

I must run the app in IE8 mode for other technical reasons.
How can I correct this problem?

My zfapp.html having

doc type

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    -------------------------
    -------------------------
```

My notch.ui.xml

```
    <ui:style>  
     .textarea{
      font-size: 11px;
      font-family: arial;
      background-color: #E6E6E6;    
      height:190px;
      width:385px;  
      resize: none;
     }
    </ui:style>  

<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="panel">          

  <div id="ControlContainer">
       <g:TextArea ui:field="txtNotch" styleName="{style.textarea}"></g:TextArea>
  </div>        

</g:HTMLPanel>
```